# Eclipse web service + EMF + Teneo

Tags: eclipse, web-services, eclipselink

Briefly what I have done is a EMF project that model a shop and its products. The model is stored in a Mysql database using Teneo and EclipseLink. 
Until now everything is fine. But now what I want is to create a webService where operations are exposed for example: addShop(String shopName) etcc.

So I create a Dynamic web project then a web service bottom up. 
Now how can I invoke operation of the EMF project for example store the name sent send with a SOAP request? Should I include in the Dynamic web project the EMF model too?
Is architectural correct what am I doing?

Thank you for your answers.